# The dropdown list is not responding properly in DT table (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

i am developing the app with DT table. One of the column must contain the dropdown list.

Upon the selection of the value from the list i want to update the string output. As an example i am using the instance of the shiny app from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215607/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny). The example works fine but not locally.

When i am running the app on my laptop the app works without errors but the string output is not being updated upon the click on the dropdown list.

I am at loss what is going wrong. I have tried [other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344974/dt-dynamically-change-column-values-based-on-selectinput-from-another-column-in/69389649#69389649) but the outcome is the same - no updates upon the click on the dropdown list.

I would be grateful if someone could make a hint.

**My App:**

```
`   library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      title = 'Selectinput column in a table',
      h3("Source:", tags$a("Yihui Xie", href = "https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/")),
      DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
      verbatimTextOutput('sel')
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      data <- head(iris, 5)
  
      for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
        data$species_selector[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "", choices =    unique(iris$Species), width = "100px"))
    }
  
      output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
        data, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
        options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
        callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
  
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
    })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

**My environment settings:**
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

```
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.15.0 DT_0.32           shiny_1.8.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.12       rstudioapi_0.15.0 magrittr_2.0.3    xtable_1.8-4      R6_2.5.1         
[6] rlang_1.1.3       fastmap_1.1.1     tools_4.2.1       cli_3.6.1         jquerylib_0.1.4  
[11] withr_3.0.0       crosstalk_1.2.1   htmltools_0.5.7   ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.3.8       
[16] digest_0.6.34     lifecycle_1.0.4   crayon_1.5.2      later_1.3.2       sass_0.4.8       
[21] htmlwidgets_1.6.4 promises_1.2.1    memoise_2.0.1     cachem_1.0.8      mime_0.12        
[26] compiler_4.2.1    bslib_0.6.1       jsonlite_1.8.8    httpuv_1.6.14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- you set `selectize = FALSE` in `selectInput` (it is `TRUE` by default) and then you just have to add the options `preDrawCallback` and `drawCallback` as in the app below;
- or you keep `selectize = TRUE` but then you also have to include the HTML dependencies (the **selectize** JavaScript library) in your app, and you have to initialize the dropdown lists by calling the `selectize()` method in the option `initComplete`; this is what I do in the app below

The dropdown lists are more stylish with `selectize = TRUE`. Moreover it is possible to include some options in the call to the `selectize()` method.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# this selectInput will not be included in the app;
# we just use it to extract the required HTML dependencies
select_input <- selectInput("x", label = NULL, choices = c("A", "B"))
deps <- htmltools::findDependencies(select_input)
# now you just have to include tagList(deps) somewhere in the Shiny UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectinput column in a table',
  DTOutput('foo'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sel'),
  tagList(deps)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- head(iris, 5)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    data$species_selector[i] <- 
      as.character(
        selectInput(
          paste0("sel", i), "", 
          choices = unique(iris$Species), 
          width = "100px"
        )
      )
  }
  
  output$foo = renderDT({
    datatable(
      data, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', 
      options = list(
        dom = 't', 
        paging = FALSE, 
        ordering = FALSE,
        initComplete = JS(c(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          "  var $table = this.api().table().node().to$();",
          "  $table.find('[id^=sel]').selectize();", # apply selectize() to all elements whose id starts with 'sel' (here sel1, sel2, ...)
          "}"
        )),
        preDrawCallback = 
          JS("function() {Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}"),
        drawCallback 
        = JS("function() {Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}")
      )  
    )
  })

  output$sel = renderPrint({
    str(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```