# DataTable not diplaying correctly after being updated

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity, shinywidgets

This question is a continuation of  my previous one about [Re-binding the SelectInput of a DataTable after being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218233/re-binding-the-selectinput-of-a-datatable-after-being-updated).

So, I made quite some progress on this app and I have reached a result that perfectly fits my needs. The app correctly updates the target database and the selectInputs as well as the filter are intuitive and user-friendly enought for what I seek.

There is however one issue, not a critical one but still rather annoying. When the "Update Data" button is clicked on and the underlying data is updated, the displayed datatable acts as if there where no category selected in the filter and returns an empty table. This issue is fixed the moment a modification is made on the filtered categories through the filter button and it doesn't stop the database to be correctly updated, but this is not an expected behaviour.

What is weird is that it seems to be caused by the the virtualSelectInput filter and not the fact that the underlying is filtered, because when I filter it directly in the code, it works just fine. Well aside from the fact that when doing the latter options, if the "Update Data" button is clicked on while no SelectInput has been changed, it will not trigger any update after that even if a SelectInput was later on changed to another value, whereas it works as intended as long as a SelectInput has been changed vefore each time the "Update Data" button has been triggered.

I suspect those two issues to be related one way or another. Is there something that I missed or mishandled ?

Below are the records of the issues :

[image: First Issue]

- Issue where the DataTable is empty after an update, but display the change after resetting the filters

[image: Normal Behaviour]

- Without the virtualSelectInput acting as a filter (expected behaviour)

[image: Issue 2]

- Without the virtualSelectInput acting as a filter, but without changing a SelectInput before updating a first time (cannot update a change after that)

## Edit

You can now run the code without setting up the database beforehand, making the error reproduci with the following R code alone

**Here is the code used to create the app :**

```
### Libraries

{
  library(shiny)            # used to create the Shiny App
  library(bslib)            # used to create the framework of the Shiny App
  library(shinyWidgets)     # used to create various widgets
  
  library(RMySQL)           # used to create and access the Database
  
  library(tidyverse)        # used for many things (mainly data manipulation)
  library(DT)               # used for creating interactive DataTable
}

### JS Module
# Unbinds the Select Input ids when "Update Data" is clicked

js <- c(
  "$('#updateButton').on('click', function() {",
  "  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());",
  "});"
)


# Initialize the dummy database
divinite_data <- tibble(
  ID = 1:11,
  Divinite = c("Quetzalcoatl", "Odin", "Ra", "Zeus", "Tiamat", "Isis", "Hades", "Thot", "Thor", "Persephone", "Amatsu"),
  ID_pantheon = c(5, 3, 2, 8, 4, 10, rep(0, 5))
)

pantheon_data <- tibble(
  id_pantheon = c(0:12),
  nom_pantheon = c("Non Défini", "Grec", "Egyptien", "Nordique", "Sumerien", "Azteque", "Japonais", rep(c("Mineure", "Majeure"), 3)),
  id_parent = c(rep(NA, 7), rep(1:3, each = 2))
)

con <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                 dbname = ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
             name = "Z_TEST",
             value = divinite_data)

dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
             name = "Z_TEST2",
             value = pantheon_data)


### Queries

QDisplay <- "
  SELECT ID, Divinite, 
  Z_TEST.ID_pantheon AS ID_Panth, PT1.id_parent AS ID_Panth_parent, PT1.nom_pantheon AS Pantheon, PT2.nom_pantheon AS Panth_parent
  
  FROM Z_TEST
  LEFT JOIN Z_TEST2 AS PT1 ON Z_TEST.ID_pantheon = PT1.id_pantheon
  LEFT JOIN Z_TEST2 AS PT2 ON PT2.id_pantheon = PT1.id_parent;
"

QGetID <- "
  SELECT id_pantheon AS ID_Panth
  FROM Z_TEST2 
  WHERE nom_pantheon = '%s'
"

QGetIDIfParent <- "
  SELECT PT1.id_pantheon AS ID_Panth
  FROM Z_TEST2 AS PT1
  LEFT JOIN Z_TEST2 AS PT2 ON PT2.id_pantheon = PT1.id_parent
  WHERE PT1.nom_pantheon = '%s'AND PT2.nom_pantheon = '%s'
"

QEdit <- "
  UPDATE Z_TEST
  SET ID_pantheon = %d
  WHERE ID = %d
"

QRef <- "
  SELECT PT1.id_pantheon AS ID_Panth, PT1.nom_pantheon AS Panth_nom, PT1.id_parent AS ID_Panth_parent, PT2.nom_pantheon AS Panth_nom_parent
  FROM Z_TEST2 AS PT1
  LEFT JOIN Z_TEST2 AS PT2 ON PT2.id_pantheon = PT1.id_parent
"


### Useful functions

# Create levels to choose from in the Select Input
factorOptions <- function(factor_levels) {
  optionList <- ""
  for (i in factor_levels) {
    optionList <- paste0(optionList, '<option value="', i, '">', i, '</option>\n')}
  
  return(optionList)
}

# Create the Select Input with ID and corresponding entry from the joined table
mySelectInput <- function(id_list, selected_factors, factor_levels) {
  select_input <- paste0('<select id="single_select_', id_list, '"style="width: 100%;">\n', 
                         sprintf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>\n', selected_factors, selected_factors), 
                         factorOptions(factor_levels), '</select>')
  return(select_input)
}

# Get the reference levels for the Select Input and Filter
dt_panth_ref <- dbGetQuery(con, QRef) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(unique_libelle = ifelse(is.na(Panth_nom_parent), Panth_nom, paste0(Panth_nom_parent, " / ", Panth_nom)), 
         Categorie = ifelse(is.na(Panth_nom_parent), Panth_nom, Panth_nom_parent))

# Preset options for the displayed table
displayTable <- function(data) {
  displayed_table <- datatable(
    data = data    , 
    selection = 'none', escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0:6))),
    callback = JS(js), extensions = "KeyTable",
    options = list(
      keys = TRUE,
      pageLength = 15,
      preDrawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
      drawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
    )
  )
  return(displayed_table)
}


### Shiny App

ui <- page_sidebar(
  sidebar = card_body(
    virtualSelectInput(
      inputId = "idFilter",
      label = "Filtre :",
      choices = prepare_choices(
        dt_panth_ref,
        label = Panth_nom,
        value = ID_Panth,
        group_by = Categorie
      ),
      multiple = TRUE,
      selected = 0:12,
      width = "100%",
      dropboxWrapper = "body"
    ), br(),
    actionButton("updateButton", "Update Data")
  ),
  card(DTOutput("interactiveTable"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Fetch the underlying data
  panth_data <- reactiveVal()
  observe(panth_data(dbGetQuery(con, QDisplay) %>% as_tibble() %>% replace_na(list(Pantheon = "Non Défini")) %>% 
                       mutate(unique_libelle = ifelse(is.na(Panth_parent), Pantheon, paste0(Panth_parent, " / ", Pantheon))) %>%
                       filter(ID_Panth %in% input$idFilter)
  ))
  
  # Initialize the DataTable
  output$interactiveTable <- renderDT({
    filt_panth <- panth_data() %>% filter(ID_Panth %in% input$idFilter)
    
    if (nrow(filt_panth) > 0) {
      displayTable(data = filt_panth %>% mutate(Select_Pantheon = mySelectInput(ID, unique_libelle, dt_panth_ref %>% pull(unique_libelle))))
    } else {
      displayTable(data = filt_panth %>% mutate(Select_Pantheon = NA))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$updateButton, {
    rows_filtered <- input$interactiveTable_rows_all
    rows_displayed <- rows_filtered[1:min(length(rows_filtered), input$interactiveTable_state$length)]
    
    # Fetch the corresponding ID of the selected gamme and update the database
    for (h in panth_data()$ID[rows_displayed]) {
      h_input <- as.character(input[[paste0("single_select_", h)]])
      current_h <- filter(panth_data(), ID == h)$unique_libelle
      
      if (h_input != current_h) {
        split_input <- str_split(h_input, " / ")[[1]]
        
        if (length(split_input) == 1) {
          i <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf(QGetID, split_input))$ID_Panth
        } else {
          i <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf(QGetIDIfParent, split_input[2], split_input[1]))$ID_Panth
        }
        
        dbGetQuery(con, sprintf(QEdit, i, h))
      }
    }
    
    # Update the underlying data
    observe(
      panth_data(dbGetQuery(con, QDisplay) %>% as_tibble() %>% replace_na(list(Pantheon = "Non Défini")) %>% 
                   mutate(unique_libelle = ifelse(is.na(Panth_parent), Pantheon, paste0(Panth_parent, " / ", Pantheon))) %>% 
                   filter(ID_Panth %in% input$input$idFilter)
      ))
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    dbDisconnect(con)
    stopApp()})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello. IMHO you should minimize this code if you want to increase your chance to receive an answer. We don't all have SQL, in particular.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be cumbersome to setup. Since the SQL part works I'll change it to a DataFrame,, that should do

Comment: The code has been edited : I kept the SQL queries but the database is now created directly through the R code alone, meaning that the error is reproducible by directly running the Shiny App

Comment: Assuming I'm ok with the SQL stuff now, it's not easy to understand what your app is supposed to do. Could you include a brief description? That said, I can already note two things: 1) you have an observer inside an observer, which is very bad; in this nested observer you filter the data but this filtering is also performed in the first observer, and that looks strange.

Comment: Basically the app would allow the user to categorize each entry of the database, and for this change to be directly updated in said database. Since there are two levels of categories with the first level being the direct parent of the other (a constraint that I have to work with in the real database, here presented as the pantheon and the divinity importance), I tweaked the selectInput of each line to show both the parent category and the child category in it. [1/2]

Comment: This is because some child categories have the same name as another while having a different parent, hence the workaround to avoid confusion when using the selector.

As for the observer, which one are you talking about ? I can get rid of the one used when updating the underlying data (it doesn't seem to change anything), but if I delete the one that initializes the undelrying data it says that I cannot access "input$idFilter"  outside of a reactive consumer. Is there something else I need to change ? 

I can provide more details if needed. [2/2]

Comment: Would it be the problem: `input$input$idFilter`?..